# How to get list of Organization using API from Github Enterprise server (self-hosted server)

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to get all organization from a self-hosted github enterprise server.

I can get all organization from github.com cloud version using `GET https://api.github.com/user/orgs` but I don't know how to do it with self-hosted version. I tried following guide in this docs but it seems doesn't work: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.2/rest/orgs/orgs#list-organizations

Answer (score 0):

The list of organizations in an Enterprise server can be retrieved via the GraphQL API. There is no REST API endpoint to retrieve this data.

Source: [Github's Enterprise GraphQL documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/graphql/guides/managing-enterprise-accounts)

> you can use the Enterprise Accounts API and the Audit Log API, which are only available as GraphQL APIs.

Here is a sample [GraphQL query](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/graphql/guides/introduction-to-graphql) that can retrieve the list of organizations within the Enterprise.

```
query listOrganizationWithinEnterprise($enterprise_slug: String!) {
  enterprise(slug: $enterprise_slug) {
    name
    organizations(first:100){
      nodes{
        name
        ... on Organization{
          login
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using a variables section `{'enterprise_slug': 'your_enterprise_name_here'}`.