# How to list the enterprise account owned organization in Github

Tags: github, github-api

How to list the Github enterprise account owned organizations using the Rest API. Rest API Doc - https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/quickstart?apiVersion=2022-11-28.

Checked their doc, I cannot find the API to list the organizations owned by github enterprise account. Also, I need API to list all the users present in the enterprise account.

Answer (score 0):

The list of organizations in an Github Enterprise Cloud or Server can be retrieved via the GraphQL API. There is no REST API endpoint to retrieve this data.

Source: [Github's Enterprise GraphQL documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/graphql/guides/managing-enterprise-accounts)

> you can use the Enterprise Accounts API and the Audit Log API, which are only available as GraphQL APIs.

Here is a sample [GraphQL query](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/graphql/guides/introduction-to-graphql) that can retrieve the list of organizations within the Enterprise.

```
query listOrganizationWithinEnterprise($enterprise_slug: String!) {
  enterprise(slug: $enterprise_slug) {
    name
    organizations(first:100){
      nodes{
        name
        ... on Organization{
          login
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using a variables section `{'enterprise_slug': 'your_enterprise_name_here'}`.

Comment: [Please don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/248627) repeat [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78169644/354577)